# Is there a limit of how deep into an object Vue.js will look into? One of my deep nested properties disappears for no reason

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

For the past 2 days I've been stuck in an endless loop of console.log()-ing stuff in order to figure out where the problem stems from but I'm unable to do so. I will try to explain my problem as clearly as I can considering I don't really understand the problem either.

The story begins with this function which makes a GET request to the back-end in order to get all servers. Then the servers get committed to my servers state.

My Vuex store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        servers: []
    },
    mutations: {
        setServers(state, servers){
            state.servers = servers
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async getUserServers({commit, state}, userId){
            try {
                let response = await axios.get("/servers/" + userId)
                let servers = response.data.servers

                commit('setServers', servers)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
})

export default store
```

After doing this, I can see the array of servers in my Vue developer tools. The array looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": 2,
      "userId": 1,
      "name": "Samurai",
      "thumbnail": "http://localhost:3000/images/servers/Samurai-2fb7b598-1edd-49ae-9314-717242cba775/5a1cbd5d-e903-474c-9a08-cec719963402.png",
      "endpoint": "/3b442cd7-34e8-4931-bfa1-76e2bebf863f",
      "users": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "Test",
            "email": "test@abv.bg",
            "image": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/733747075455647898/738360317209214976/1.png",
         }
      ],
      "rooms": [
         {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "General",
            "serverId": 2,
            "messages": [
               {
                  "id": 7,
                  "message": "test",
                  "roomId": 2,
                  "userId": 1,
                  "user": {
                     "id": 1,
                     "username": "Test",
                     "email": "test@abv.bg",
                     "image": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/733747075455647898/738360317209214976/1.png",
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see, the `server[0].rooms[0].messages[0]` shows the first message object of the server. You can clearly see that the message object has a `user` property which contains info about the user who created this message.

Now this is where my problem starts. I have a component in which I use a computed property that finds and return a server from the `servers` array:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="server" v-if='server'>
        {{ server }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            serverEndpoint: this.$route.params.endpoint
        }
    },
    computed: {
        server(){
            let server = this.$store.state.servers.find((server) => {
                return server.endpoint == '/' + this.serverEndpoint
            })

            return server
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Whenever I render the server that has been found, I get this:

```
{
   "id": 2,
   "userId": 1,
   "name": "Samurai",
   "thumbnail": "http://localhost:3000/images/servers/Samurai-2fb7b598-1edd-49ae-9314-717242cba775/5a1cbd5d-e903-474c-9a08-cec719963402.png",
   "endpoint": "/3b442cd7-34e8-4931-bfa1-76e2bebf863f",
   "server_user": {
      "id": 2,
      "userId": 1,
      "serverId": 2
   },
   "users": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "username": "Test",
         "email": "Test@abv.bg",
         "image": "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/733747075455647898/738360317209214976/1.png",
         "server_user": {
            "id": 2,
            "userId": 1,
            "serverId": 2
         }
      }
   ],
   "rooms": [
      {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "General",
         "serverId": 2,
         "messages": [
            {
               "id": 7,
               "message": "test",
               "roomId": 2,
               "userId": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can clearly see, the `user` property in server.rooms[0].messages[0] that was available earlier no longer exists. This is my problem, I have no idea why is it disappearing. I'm not doing any alterations to the `servers` array whatsoever. I'm starting to think it has something to do with how deep it is nested in the object but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Rather than checking in the Vue devtools, could you confirm that the `user` property is definitely present in the axios response? Check the *Network* tab.

Comment: @skirtle Yes, the network tab indeed shows that the user property is present in the response. The problem definitely stems from the front-end.

Comment: Do you have `strict` mode enabled on the store? After you render the component and see the missing `user` property, is that same property still present inside the store data or does it disappear from there too?

Comment: The `server` that your computed property produces is missing other data too (`createdAt`). It is not the same object. It's impossible to tell you what you are doing wrong because the code you have provided is superficial. What does your `setServers` mutation do? Can you do some manual investigation by checking the `servers` state contains the data you expect?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Oh I deleted all createdAt and updatedAt on purpose to make the object easier to read by you guys but it seems I forgot to delete a couple of them. setServers literally just assigns the servers to the vuex state servers. I'll add it to the question.